# My Implementation of SimpleModal isn't working

Tags: simplemodal

I'm a total jQuery noob and I'm trying to use [Eric Martin's SimpleModal Confirm Override dialog box](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) in an ASP.Net web page. It's not working - no surprise, I have no idea what I'm doing! Here's a simplified version of my aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Reimbursements.aspx.cs" Inherits="EAS.telecom.Reimbursements" MasterPageFile="~/common/default.master"  Title="Reimbursements" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/common/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='~/jquery/confirm/js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='~/jquery/confirm/js/jquery.simplemodal.js'>
        $.modal('#confirm');</script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='~/jquery/confirm/js/confirm.js'></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        //some regular javascript here
</script>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEmployeeInfo" Enabled="false">
<div id='content'>
        <div id='confirm-dialog'>
            <h3>Confirm Override</h3>
            <p>A modal dialog override of the JavaScript confirm function. Demonstrates the use of the <code>onShow</code> callback as well as how to display a modal dialog confirmation instead of the default JavaScript confirm dialog.</p>
            <input type='button' name='confirm' class='confirm' value='Demo'/> or <a href='#' class='confirm'>Demo</a>
        </div>

        <!-- modal content -->
        <div id='confirm'>
            <div class='header'><span>Confirm</span></div>
            <div class='message'></div>
            <div class='buttons'>
                <div class='no simplemodal-close'>No</div><div class='yes'>Yes</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- preload the images -->
        <div style='display:none'>
            <img src='~/jquery/confirm/img/confirm/header.gif' alt='' />
            <img src='~/jquery/confirm/img/confirm/button.gif' alt='' />
        </div>
    </div>
     //more controls, including an AJAX TabContainer
    </asp:Panel></asp:Content>
```

When I run the page, I see the Demo button and the Demo link, but clicking on them does nothing. What am I missing? Can I use SimpleModal on an ASP.Net page? Within a Content control?  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues here.

- A `script` tag with a `src` cannot also contain script body. So, this is invalid.

  `<script src='~/jquery/confirm/js/jquery.simplemodal.js'>$.modal('#confirm');</script>`
- If you use an ID, SimpleModal is called like so: `$('#content').modal();`
- That call needs to be within a click event handler.

  `<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('a.confirm').click(function () {
          $('#content').modal();
      });
  });
  </script>`

Comment: Updated for fool-proofing. You can put the tag anywhere you like.

Comment: Part of what's confusing me is that that script code with the click event handler is included in the confirm.js script file (downloaded from SimpleModal), which I reference in a script tag. Do I have to put a script tag with the click event handler in my aspx page also?